# How can I loop through a global namespace of constants?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global namespace of constants, how to I dynamically loop through these?

```
$.sKey = {
    k1: '9t1q6g',
    k2: 'o849nc',
    k3: 'xs96hn',
    k4: 'jb24nc',
    k5: 'iqokpb'
};
```

I have tried adaptations of the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    alert($.skey.k + i);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a foreach loop:

```
for (var key in $.sKey) alert($.sKey[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through the js object with

```
for (var k in $.sKey) {
```

and check if the attribute is not inherited. like

```
if ($.sKey.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
```

like

```
for (var k in $.sKey) {
      if ($.sKey.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        console.log(k,$.sKey[k]);
      }
}
```

Here is [**a sample fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj76f/)

Answer (score -1):

like this

```
for(var key in $.sKey) 
    {
         alert($.sKey[key]);
    }
```

Comment: -1 for not providing a single word of comment.

Comment: Does JavaScript support this flexible `for loop` ?

Answer (score -1):

Use each in jquery  to retrieve all data

```
 $.each($sKey,function(i,val){
alert(val);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V5T6Y/4/)

Comment: -1 for using Jquery for trivialities.

Comment: @Kay Question taged with jquery .that is why i used .it is not problem

Answer (score -2):

if you are using jquery you can change your codes into this:

```
var sKey = {
k1: '9t1q6g',
k2: 'o849nc',
k3: 'xs96hn',
k4: 'jb24nc',
k5: 'iqokpb'
};
$.each(sKey,function(key,value){
    console.log("key:"+key+"value:"+value);
})
```

You can see a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Rqp4/)

Comment: -1 for using Jquery for trivialities.